# Update multiple rows in MySQL when using WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table with two columns user_id, cumulative_score. I have a process which evaulates a bunch of users on a task and assigns scores to them. Now I have to udpate the cumulative scores of users. Is it possible to do it in a single query

```
UPDATE scores where user_id = "a" set score = score + a_score 
and where user_id = "b" set score = score + b_score
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're looking for [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case):

```
UPDATE scores SET 
    score = score + (CASE WHEN user_id = 'a' THEN a_score ELSE b_score END) 
WHERE 
    user_id = 'a' OR user_id = 'b';
```

Depending on the situation though, you might be better off with just running separate queries. (This query is already rather painful to read, and the repetition of user_id is icky.)

Comment: If I want to insert the row if it is not already present can i use

    INSERT INTO my_tables... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    above_query_in_your_answer